# Namespaces in Streaming API for XML (StaX)

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'm fairly new to XML and StaX. I need to generate the following XML namespaces using StaX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a xmlns="urn:blah blah"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:blah blah.xsd">
     <other tags go here.../>
</a>
```

I've tried a variety of things including using Namespace and QName objects and eventFactory.createStartElement but I can't get the "xsi:schemaLocation" line to work.

What I have so far is...

```
    ArrayList<Namespace> nameSpaces = new ArrayList<>();

    Namespace nameSpace2 = eventFactory.createNamespace("xsi",
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    Namespace nameSpace3 = eventFactory.createNamespace("xsi:schemaLocation",
            "urn:blah.xsd");
    Namespace nameSpace1 = eventFactory.createNamespace("urn:blah");

    nameSpaces.add(nameSpace1);
    nameSpaces.add(nameSpace2);
    nameSpaces.add(nameSpace3);

    StartElement startElement = eventFactory.createStartElement(new QName(
            "a"), nameSpaces.iterator(), null);

    eventWriter.add(startElement);
    eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createDTD("\n"));
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Thanks

Russ

Answer (score 0):

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:blah blah.xsd"
```

isn't a namespace declaration, it is an attribute in the `"xsi"` namespace.